# MySQL: Selecting boolean value from JSON field

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, mysql-json

I'm using MySQL 5.7.19

I'm trying to retrieve a class that looks as follows

```
class Task
{
    public $title;
    public $done;
}
```

the `title` and `done` properties are saved in a JSON column.

The code that I use to retrieve looks as follows:

```
    $tasksSql = <<<'EOT'
    SELECT  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.title')) AS title,
            JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.done') AS done
                FROM Tasks WHERE TaskListId = ?;
EOT;
    $tasksStatement = $connection->prepare($tasksSql);
    $tasksStatement->execute([$id]);
    $tasksStatement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Task");
    $taskList->tasks = $tasksStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Task");
```

It fills out all the fields, but the `done` property gets set the string values "true" or "false" instead of a boolean value.

Comment: what string value do you get back? "1" or "true" ?

Comment: "true" or "false"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think PDO is not recognizing the Boolean value being returned, and it is just assuming its all just string. This has nothing to do with JSON being used. You could change in your query

```
JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.done') AS done
```

into

```
JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.done') = true AS done
```

to change it into a integer 0/1 instead.

Or change your PHP code to parse the returned value into a Boolean. For example by adding a constructor for the `tasks` object:

```
class Task {
    public $title; // string
    public $done; // bool
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->done = $done == 'true';
    }
}
```

Or even let PDO use an anonymous function for the conversion:

```
$taskList->tasks = $tasksStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_FUNC, function($title, $done) { $task = new Task(); $task->title = $title; $task->done = $done == 'true'; return $task;});
```

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work either. The properties get set to the string values "1" or "0".

Comment: i assume the PDO is not recognizing the Boolean. You can confirm this by quickly justing the query into `select 'foo' as title, true as done;` ... I think you will still get string 'true'...

Comment: That is right. Does that mean you can't parse any boolean value using PDO? I've never been a fan of PHP, but this language never stops disappointing.

Comment: @Philippe I've edited the answer to add in some options.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using the constructor work around.